# width on element and z-index

Tags: html, css

I am just playing a little bit around with a landing page.

I just set a red opacity background on "A CATCHY PIECE OF TEXT".

- How do I set the width on that the correct way, so I also have the responsive part in mind?
- How can I get the font in front, and the red background in the back?

```css
    #cathyText {
        background-color: red;
        padding: 10px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
```

```html
     <h2 class="text-center" id="cathyText">A CATCHY PIECE OF TEXT</h2>
```

Comment: Please include the code in question into your question!

Comment: Your comment does not make sense, The relevant code and link to the website is there.

Comment: Yes it does. Have a look at the help center (rules) on this site. Code hosted on different websites isn't allowed

Comment: Nevermind other people could help me solve my problem "without including the code in question into my question. What ever that means.

Comment: My OCD is kicking in: Just make sure you spell "piece" and "catchy" right.

Comment: I got you on my blacklist, @McDuck4

Comment: Haha thank you for that @DrewKennedy :) I will correct that now. Bye bye baao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the font in front, and the red background in the back?

Use `rgba()`:

```
#cathyText {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The reason it works is the first 3 numbers set the red-green-blue of the color, and the last sets the opacity.

If you want to center your `<h2>` element, one way is to place it in a wrapper and change the display to `inline-block`:

```css
#cathyText {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.catchy-text-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="catchy-text-wrapper">
 <h2 class="text-center" id="cathyText">A CATCY PEICE OF TEXT</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I was just thinking of the width og the red background. I actually thought that had to be procent? The width of the background should only be around 200px. But if I give it a width in % or pixel, it is gonna be left-aligned.

Comment: Ok I thought so, that I had to wrap it. Perfect, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

use `rgba()` for background color

```
#cathyText {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
    padding: 10px;
    /* opacity: 0.1; */
    z-index: auto;
}
```